# Calling the doPost in another Webapp with a Req Dispatcher forward

Tags: java, servlets

I have 2 web apps, no front-end(i.e html/Jsp) in either. Both have one servlet each.
Lets call them WebApp1/WebApp2 and ServiceServlet1/ServiceServlet2.
I have 2 war files, WebApp1.war and WebApp2.war and both deployed.

I call the ServiceServlet1 directly from the browser with -
`http://localhost:8080/WebApp1/ServiceServlet1`
Obviously the doGet method will be called(POST is associated only with FORM, correct me if I am wrong).
The ServiceServlet1 is build something like -

```
    public class ServiceServlet1 extends HttpServlet {
     @Override
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse)
       throws ServletException, IOException {
      doPost(httpRequest, httpResponse);
     }

     @Override
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
       HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException,
       IOException {
      RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher;

      try {
// Process something
       requestDispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WebApp2/ServiceServlet2");
       requestDispatcher.forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
      } catch (IOException ioException) {
       ioException.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ServletException servletException) {
       servletException.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
    }
```

Essentially, what I require is to call the `doPost()` of `ServiceServlet2`
I have tried few different ways with `httpReq.getRequestDispatcher()`, `sendRedirect`  etc. but have failed so far.

So how can I make it happen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answer of ckuetbach, you can't change the request method when dispatching the request. If the second servlet cannot be changed to execute the same business logic on `doGet()` as well, then you have to fire a POST request yourself programmatically.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://localhost/WebApp2/ServiceServlet2").openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
// ... Write to OutputStream of your HttpServletResponse?
```

#### See also:

- [How to use `URLConnection` to fire and handle HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: "If the second servlet is really that bad designed and you cannot fix it to be more flexible" - I didnt quite get what you mean by, if you can pls elaborate. Can you pls tell what options are possible here, I mean in context of making the second servlet more flexible. Any flipside to the solution you have provided?

Comment: Now I reread it, I must admit that it sounds a bit harsh. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Just to confirm. The data I have to send to the second servlet, I will write through the OutputStream, which is a String(right?), consider it to be an xml file content. The HttpReq obj of the second servlet will then contain this file content and I can extract through `httpReq.getInputStream()`. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: Just write it as query string in request body like `name=value` and then it'll just be available by `request.getParameter("name")`. See also the linked article.

Answer (score 0):

The two servlets don't share the same Classloader, because they are in different ´*.WAR´-files.

As far as I know, you have to chances to do what you want:

1. Disable Classloader-Separation in tomcat (I've never done this tomcat)
2. Repackage the two aplication within one `*.WAR`